# Drawing Transparent Images

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, drawrect, nsimage

I created a custom view to a button, as I need to implement some highlighting when the mouse is over. The class is very simple, and I already implemented `mouseEntered:` as well as `mouseExited:`. The view was registered for tracking in the init method (not sure if it's the best place).

The problem is drawing. I keep an ivar `mouseOver`, set to `YES` on mouse enter and `NO` on mouse exited. The other ivar is for the image, called `image`. The difference between mouse over or not when it comes to drawing, is the transparency. Here is my `drawRect:`:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [image drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0,0.0)
              fromRect:dirtyRect
             operation:NSCompositeCopy
              fraction:((mouseOver) ? 1.0 : 0.0)];
}
```

It works nicely, but only when the mouse first entered, apparently. I guess the problem is that the view is not cleared before drawing the other image. I tried adding:

```
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFillUsingOperation(dirtyRect, NSCompositeClear);
```

But without success. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[NSColor clearColor]` is a purely transparent color. You probably want to fill using a color with some opacity, like, say, `[NSColor whiteColor]`.

Comment: Hmm, I understand. But I don't want to fill it with a color, if possible. Clearing the view would mean letting it transparent.